# Cloud Scheduler invoked Twice in 10 mins

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

We have a cloud scheduler that runs at an interval of every 6 hours and calls an application deployed in GKE (single Pod) via HTTP. We are observing a strange behaviour where the application is called a second time at 10th min of the initial run. The job runs for nearly an hour.
So, at the end, we finally see two parallel processing of the same event with the diff of 10 mins. Any pointers will be helpful :slightly_smiling_face:

Comment: Do you have retries policies? Do you acknowledge the CLoud Scheduler http request before the attemptDeadline?

Comment: attemptDeadline is set to 45 mins and the job which takes 1 hour to complete doesn't complete within that, so the task is marked as failed which really is not a problem for me. I have set it to 0 retries.

Comment: Did you look into the logs? Are you sure that is an automatic trigger and not a manual trigger?

Comment: Hello, is the scheduler job the only source of triggering the application deployed in GKE ?